# SQL Query to checks on the column that always continue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named GRADE and has columns GRADE_NAME, POIN_FROM, POIN_TO.
GRADE table looks like this :

```
GRADE_NAME        POIN_MIN       POIN_MAX
A                      90           100
B                      75            89
C                      50            69
D                      30            49
E                      10            29
F                       0            10
```

Now, i want to write an sql query to check that all values in column poin_min and poin_max are valid. 
In this case, if poin_min and poin_max contains values such as the above, my query should return 1 (false) because each value are not mutually sequential.

- poin_max for grade F should be 9.
- poin_min for grade B should be 70.

But, if the value is always a sequence then my query return 0 (true).

This is what I have tried :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(CEK) = 100 THEN '0' ELSE '1' END AS RESULT
FROM (
    SELECT POIN_MAX - POIN_MIN AS CEK
    FROM GRADE
    ORDER BY GRADE_NAME ASC
)
```

And as you see, this does not work. Because although  **SUM(CEK) = 100**, but the value does not necessarily sequence.

I am using oracle, but if anyone know how to solve this with another dbms please share, that would be very helpful.

ps : Rows for this table are dynamic. user can add some ROW for grade_name like G,H, etc. but poin_min and poin_max always 0 to 100.

Thanks,

Rubah Malam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to expand each range into its individual values, which you can do with [recursive subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG) (in 11GR2 or higher); and then look at the overall list for all grades. For example, just for F:

```
with r (grade_name, poin, poin_max) as (
  select grade_name, poin_min, poin_max
  from grade
  union all
  select r.grade_name, r.poin + 1, r.poin_max
  from r
  where r.poin < r.poin_max
)
select grade_name, poin
from r
where grade_name = 'F';

GRADE_NAME       POIN
---------- ----------
F                   0 
F                   1 
F                   2 
F                   3 
F                   4 
F                   5 
F                   6 
F                   7 
F                   8 
F                   9 
F                  10
```

To see if there are any discrepancies you can compare various counts:

```
with r (grade_name, poin, poin_max) as (
  select grade_name, poin_min, poin_max
  from grade
  union all
  select r.grade_name, r.poin + 1, r.poin_max
  from r
  where r.poin < r.poin_max
)
select count(poin), count(distinct poin), min(poin), max(poin)
from r
having count(poin) != 101
or count(distinct poin) != 101
or min(poin) != 0
or max(poin) != 100;

COUNT(POIN) COUNT(DISTINCTPOIN)  MIN(POIN)  MAX(POIN)
----------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
         97                  96          0        100
```

Or if you just want your original 0/1 result:

```
with r (grade_name, poin, poin_max) as (
  select grade_name, poin_min, poin_max
  from grade
  union all
  select r.grade_name, r.poin + 1, r.poin_max
  from r
  where r.poin < r.poin_max
)
select case when count(poin) != 101 or count(distinct poin) != 101
  or min(poin) != 0 or max(poin) != 100 then 1 else 0 end as result
from r;

    RESULT
----------
         1
```

You could also get a bit more ambitious and report the actual problem values:

```
with r (grade_name, poin, poin_max) as (
  select grade_name, poin_min, poin_max
  from grade
  union all
  select r.grade_name, r.poin + 1, r.poin_max
  from r
  where r.poin < r.poin_max
),
n as (
  select level - 1 as poin from dual
  connect by level <= 101
)
select coalesce(n.poin, r.poin),
  count(r.poin), min(r.grade_name), max(r.grade_name)
from n
full outer join r on r.poin = n.poin
group by coalesce(n.poin, r.poin)
having count(r.poin) != 1
or count(n.poin) != 1
order by coalesce(n.poin, r.poin);

COALESCE(N.POIN,R.POIN) COUNT(R.POIN) MIN(R.GRADE_NAME) MAX(R.GRADE_NAME)
----------------------- ------------- ----------------- -----------------
                     10             2 E                 F                 
                     70             0                                     
                     71             0                                     
                     72             0                                     
                     73             0                                     
                     74             0
```

Here `n` is another CTE that just generates all the expected valid values, and the outer join to the recursive CTE lets you see any that are missing from, duplicated, or present when they shouldn't be. For example if you made the range for A 90-101 instead, it would also report:

```
                    101             1 A                 A
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf6bca/4) including a range with 101; although you'd hopefully already have a constraint on the range of valid values so you wouldn't be able to create a record like that in the first place. And [another Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7dfc3/1) where the values are contiguous.

Comment: Thanks, i tried and it works. I use your second query. Because what i want is 0/1 results. I tried your 1st and 3rd query also. And the results was great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea with windowing functions: create a CTE with the previous and next row's `poin_max` (ordered by `poin_min`), then run your checks:

```
with my_grade as (
select
  lead(poin_max) over (order by poin_min) next_max
, lag(poin_max) over (order by poin_min) prev_max
, poin_min
, poin_max
from grade
)
select
  case when prev_max is null and poin_min <> 0 then 1 else 0 end min_error
, case when next_max is null and poin_max <> 100 then 1 else 0 end max_error
, case when prev_max is not null and poin_min <> prev_max + 1 then 1 else 0 end step_error
, poin_min, poin_max
, prev_max, next_max
from my_grade;
```

You'll get a 1 in `min_error` if the minimum is not zero, 1 in `max_error` if the maximum isn't 100, and a 1 in the last column if the previous max isn't exactly one below the current min.